# Sorting sections in a config file using configparser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read server details from a config file and process for some details. After processing, i wanted to write the details into an excel sheet which in fact works properly. My problem is if there are server names which starts with A, a, B, b, C and c, the details are printed in the order A, B, C, a,b and c. How can i remove case sensitivity here.

Below is how i am using the sorted method:

```
for section in sorted(config.sections()):
```

My config details are somewhat like this

```
[astro1a]
server.user_name = root
server.password = stnes
server.ip = 172.19.40.21


[astro1b]
server.user_name = root
server.password = stains
server.ip = 172.19.40.22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find interesting informations [on this python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

`config.sections()` returns a list of string

The code below may do the job:

```
sorted(config.sections(), key=str.lower)
```

Comment: I feel you are referring to a list. I am not sure how this can be done on sections.

Answer (score 0):

This converts section names to lower-case

```
sorted([sec.lower() for sec in config.sections()])
```

Comment: This is wrong. This will take only the sections which starts in lower case.